# Localization pattern with mongodb c# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I've recently started with mongodb c# driver. I need to know a pattern to localize the data in the storage. So far I've found schema like this:

```
{
  _id: "id",
  description: [{
    lan: "en-US",
    description: "name_in_english"
  }, {
    lan: "zh-TW",
    description: "name_in_traditional_chinese"
  }]
}
```

Is this a rational choice? How do I write queries to select only one description pair for a given language, to avoid loading all of the languages?

Comment: This [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17879654) could give you some directions.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a slightly different structure; the region codes can be used for a Dictionary-like structure in .NET which is more compact. You can simply inherit from `Dictionary<string, string>`, so you're using the default dictionary serializer automatically.

I have written something like this at my previous company Pactas, and the code is available open-source ([LocalizableString.cs](https://github.com/Pactas/nantero/blob/56159c39758304220b1a11e1820734b71be63210/Pactas.SDK/DTO/LocalizableString.cs)). This wasn't meant as first-level citizen, but rather as an embedded property and it will serialize to something like:

```
{
  "foo" : "bar",
  "myLocalizableString" : { 
      "_c" : "default", 
      "en" : "English (fallback)", 
      "en-US" : "American English", ... }
}
```

Concerning the traffic, I'd choose to read all data as-is an do the language-filtering in the client - if the data changes seldomly and isn't huge, that's a lot better than calling the database *at all*, but that depends on the use case, of course. However, if you have a lot of writes and a very large collection, I'd probably reverse the order and store each translation as a separate object.